# how to get data from different levels in a xmltable?

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype, xmltable

I'm trying to get the values of two attributes from table MVR_DTL in column VENDOR_XML. VENDOR_XML is of datatype clob and contains an xml that looks like this

```
<MVRCHPINFF_1.0>
   <Routing ReplyToQMgr="PQ21" ReplyToQ="A4218QA.BIZTALK.REPLY.REPORT.PROD" CorelId="712393102361590" MsgType="8" Expiry="-1" MsgID="201904051632015"></Routing>
   <MVRRecLoop>
      <CLoop>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN GENERAL</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN ST</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
      </CLoop>
      <HIJLoop>
         <JRec>
            <J_SVCDesc>MVR RECORD CLEAR</J_SVCDesc>
         </JRec>
      </HIJLoop>
      </MVRRecLoop>
</MVRCHPINFF_1.0>
```

I tried running

```
SELECT c.J_SVCDesc, c.XMLDetails from MVR_DTL M,
    XMLTABLE(
        'string-join(/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop/CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
    passing XMLTYPE(M.VENDOR_XML)
    columns XMLDetails varchar2(200) PATH '.',
            J_SVCDesc varchar2(50) PATH './../../../HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc') c;
```

and i get this error

```
Error during Execute
 S1000(19112)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: 
XVM-01020: [XPTY0020] The path step context item is not a node
```

I also tried

```
SELECT x1.J_SVCDesc, x2.XMLDetails from MVR_DTL M,  
XMLTABLE('/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop'
passing XMLTYPE(M.VENDOR_XML)
columns 
Address XMLTYPE path './CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr',
J_SVCDesc varchar(50) PATH './HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc') x1
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  'string-join(., "|")'
  PASSING x1.Address
  COLUMNS XMLDetails varchar2(200) PATH '.') x2;
```

but errored out with

```
Error during Execute
 S1000(19279)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: 
expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence
```

I'm trying to get

```
J_SVCDESC           XMLDETAILS
MVR RECORD CLEAR    ROMAN GENERAL|ROMAN ST|ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111
```

Could someone help me figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Your second 'I also tried' query doesn't error - with that sample anyway; but doesn't get quite the right result - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cde57c248762289c417a2ca29144c1c7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the string-join down to the columns clause:

```
select x.j_svcdesc, x.xmldetails
from mvr_dtl m
cross join xmltable (
  '/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop'
  passing xmltype(m.vendor_xml)
  columns J_SVCDesc varchar2(50) path 'HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc',
    xmldetails varchar2(200) path 'string-join(CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
) x
```

Demo with your sample data in a CTE:

```
with mvr_dtl (vendor_xml) as (
  select to_clob('<MVRCHPINFF_1.0>
   <Routing ReplyToQMgr="PQ21" ReplyToQ="A4218QA.BIZTALK.REPLY.REPORT.PROD" CorelId="712393102361590" MsgType="8" Expiry="-1" MsgID="201904051632015"></Routing>
   <MVRRecLoop>
      <CLoop>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN GENERAL</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN ST</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
      </CLoop>
      <HIJLoop>
         <JRec>
            <J_SVCDesc>MVR RECORD CLEAR</J_SVCDesc>
         </JRec>
      </HIJLoop>
      </MVRRecLoop>
</MVRCHPINFF_1.0>')
  from dual
)
select x.j_svcdesc, x.xmldetails
from mvr_dtl m
cross join xmltable (
  '/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop'
  passing xmltype(m.vendor_xml)
  columns J_SVCDesc varchar2(50) path 'HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc',
    xmldetails varchar2(200) path 'string-join(CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
) x;
```

```
J_SVCDESC                                          XMLDETAILS                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MVR RECORD CLEAR                                   ROMAN GENERAL|ROMAN ST|ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111
```

If the HIJLoop node name suggests there could be multiple JRec values too then you could concatenate those too:

```
  columns J_SVCDesc varchar2(50) path 'string-join(HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc, "|")',
    xmldetails varchar2(200) path 'string-join(CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
```

which makes no difference to the output with the sample XML.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52ef23b2c92b14bf89b20e4db4fab0f5)

---

Incidentally, your second attempt sort of works; it doesn't error but doesn't get the right result either. The `address` you pass is an XML fragment with just sibling nodes, and the string-join only sees one value, consisting of the `text()` from those (I think... something like that). If you pass the CLoop down instead and expand the second XPath then it works:

```
select x1.j_svcdesc, x2.xmldetails
from mvr_dtl m
cross join xmltable (
  '/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop'
  passing xmltype(m.vendor_xml)
  columns J_SVCDesc varchar(50) path 'HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc',
    HIJLoop xmltype path 'CLoop'
) x1
cross join xmltable (
  'string-join(CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
  passing x1.HIJLoop
  columns xmldetails varchar2(200) path '.'
) x2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f2fc1faf78d2ba14d92f6374154cbe8)

But if you were actually getting "ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence" then I suspect you have data that does actually have multiple JRec nodes; in which case see my second query above.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f6da931745f4e2a88f076e14cdb200a) showing that issue with this approach and my first query; and it working with my second query. So you probably need to use that:

```
select x.j_svcdesc, x.xmldetails
from mvr_dtl m
cross join xmltable (
  '/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop'
  passing xmltype(m.vendor_xml)
  columns J_SVCDesc varchar2(50) path 'string-join(HIJLoop/JRec/J_SVCDesc, "|")',
    xmldetails varchar2(200) path 'string-join(CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "|")'
) x;
```

You might need to increase the returned column sizes, too.